# Don't understand where i am going wrong with my else statement

Tags: javascript, html

I need a breakdown in laymans terms as to where I am going wrong with getting my else statement to work. I thought I had figured it out but don't understand something as I keep running into this issue. Thanks

```
      if (country === "Brazil" || "Portugal") {
        alert("You speak Portuguese");
      } else {
        alert("You don't speak Portuguese");
      }
```

Comment: `if (country === "Brazil" || country === "Portugal") {...}`

Comment: Thank you! What if I am trying to get it to still say you speak Portuguese when they mispell brazil to brasil or portugel?

Comment: There's a few ways you could do that. In you case, the easiest would probably be just to add additional checks to the `if` statement: https://jsfiddle.net/0cqbt7nf/1/

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following:

```
if (country === "Brazil" || country === "Portugal") {
  alert("You speak Portuguese");
} else {
  alert("You don't speak Portuguese");
}
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you that does help! hank you! What if I am trying to get it to still say you speak Portuguese when they misspell brazil to brasil or portugel?